# Base64 encoding in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

my script includes this line:

```
encoded = "Basic " + s.encode("base64").rstrip()
```

But gives me back the error:

```
LookupError: 'base64' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs
```

This line seemed to work fine in python 2 but since switching to 3 I get the error

Comment: Yes, this string codec was removed in Python 3

Comment: If you want to do Base64 encoding in Python 3, you'd probably want to use the `base64` module.

Comment: ^Of which was just showed by @warvariuc in his answer.

Answer (score 9):

This string codec was removed in Python 3. Use [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) module:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Mar 23 2017, 16:49:06)

>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode('whatever')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>>> base64.b64encode(b'whatever')
b'd2hhdGV2ZXI='
>>>
```

Don't forget to convert the data to bytes.

Comment: In addition to this, you may want to use `bytes()` to convert a `str` to a bytes-like object. For example, `bytes('python3', 'utf-8')` would give us `b'python3'`.

Comment: It wasn't removed, it just can't be used with `str.encode()` anymore because it translates bytes to bytes and is not a text encoding for that reason. `codecs.encode(b'whatever', 'base64')` is closer to what was used in python2, and you don't have to remember which module to import for which codec.

Comment: @mata I meant it was removed from codecs available in string. `bytes` objects don't have `encode`.

Comment: @warvariuc, that would do then. Then again, both will still produce the same output anyways. Are there any performance differences between `str.encode()` and `bytes()`?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais Don't estimate, measure! :)

Comment: @warvariuc I guess I have another investigation to do then. Haha!

Answer (score 5):

Code as follows:

```
base64.urlsafe_b64encode('Some String'.encode('UTF-8')).decode('ascii')
```

**For example:** `return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode('UTF-8')).decode('ascii')}`

**Worked for me.**